# Why is a larger sample required for a weaker rate when the response is a binary event?

Tags: binomial-distribution, binary-data, statistical-power

I am interested in conducting an experiment and am attempting to calculate the sample size required for this experiment. If I hold beta at 0.8, alpha at .95, and am looking for a 5% increase, why do I need a larger sample for a smaller conversion ratio?  For example lets use 70%, 50% and 30%.

I am doing this as an exercise on the side and considering running this as a pet project on a site but really want to just understand the concept as clearly I am missing something.

Comment: The amount of data you would need for 70% is exactly the same as 30%. Note also that a 5% increase is not a constant increase as the base rate changes (ie, 2% -> 7% is not the same as 48% -> 53%).

Comment: So the reason for the difference is that the increase is not constant and to deem a 5% increase off of a lower (30%) base requires more data than a 5% increase on a higher (70%) base?